# Liquid Warning: Liquid syntax error (line 1): Unexpected character in "{{site.pages, group_by: "category" }}"

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I'm trying to make a site in jekyll. The following code seems to work, but it clutters logs with this error:

```
Liquid Warning: Liquid syntax error (line 1): Unexpected character   in "{{site.pages | group_by: "category" }}" in /home/why/projects/jekyll-gitbook/_pages/categories.md
```

The page code:

```
---
title: categories
layout: post
category: Guides
permalink: /categories/
lang: en
---
{% assign categories = site.pages | group_by: 'category' %}
{% for category in categories %}
  * {{ category.name }}
    {% for page in category.items %}
      * <a href="{{site.baseurl}}{{page.url}}">{{ page.title | escape }}</a>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

How to get rid of this warning?

Comment: Hi and welcome. First line can be caused by `Encoding` UTF8 vs. UTF8-BOM or may you have a hidden symbol before FrontMatter. 
Your error message `{% assign categories = site.pages | group_by: 'category' %}
{% for category in categories %}` does NOT fit to the code (in code you have an additional assign step)